# Proove $||\xi||^\alpha =\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (\cos(\xi y) - 1) {||y||^{-(n+\alpha)}} \: dy$

Tags: integration

I came a across a problem I can't solve.

Given $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha\in (0,2)$, proove:

$||\xi||^\alpha =\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (\cos(\xi y^T) - 1) {||y||^{-(n+\alpha)}} \: dy$

for any $\xi,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and ||·|| being the Euclidean norm

Comment: LHS is positive and RHS is $\leq 0$ so the equation is obviously wrong.